# Streaming file via HTTP to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Currently we have a function on one of our EC2 instances (running C# .NET) that, upon request, opens an HTTP connection to an external site (for the sake of argument, let's say https://www.example.com/file.csv (which requires basic auth)) to download a file. Once we store the file to memory, we then connect to S3 and store that file into a bucket.

I am moving the surrounding functionality out of the EC2 and into a step function which fires off a series of lambdas.

I am trying to find the best service for handling the process of opening the HTTP connection and storing the file off to S3. The problem with using a Lambda is that the external site is *slooooow* and it often takes over an hour to retrieve the file from them.

Any thoughts on a good option for handling this need?

Comment: Do you manage the external site?

Comment: @Algeriassic no

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Lambda is maxed to 15 minutes.

You need to implement some sort of a chain so your function starts from where the last Lambda execution stopped.

For example, your Lambda starts the download from 0% and when it is close to 15 minutes, your function downloaded 20% of the file. And kicks another instance of the function to take over from the 20% and kill the first one or it will timeout when it reaches 15 minutes. Then keep the same logic until you download the file.

Since you have mentioned that the download takes over an hour, I would advise you to use an EC2 instance for the download then use Lambda for any other short tasks.